# Removing italic and bold html tags from string?

Tags: java, html, regex

What is a safer way to remove bold and italics than the following?

```
        String text = "<b>Remove <i>bold</i> and italics</b>";
        System.out.println(text);
        text = text.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", ""); //remove all but only want to remove b and i?
        System.out.println(text);
```

Also, and more extensible (if I want to include other tags such as "strong" or "em" and allow for case sensitivity "b" vs "B" etc,.)?

Comment: Safer way is definitely not using regex. For safe way use HTM/XML parser. btw your regex is removing all HTML tags not just bold, italics etc.

Comment: @anubhava: In his case I believe Regex is ok to use. See http://www.rubular.com/r/LBFMYx2Sso

Comment: That is still somewhat unsafe and is true only if input HTML is well formed. What if closing `>` is missing in HTML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this regex :
          `<\/?[bi]>`

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eA8gR8/4)**

**CODE :**

```
    String text = "<b>Remove <i>bold</i> and italics</b>"; 
    text = text.replaceAll("<\\/?[bi]>", "");  
    System.out.println(text);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Remove bold and italics
```

If you want to match case insensitive then you can use [corresponding flag](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2003/04/RegexTutorial.htm) `(?i)`

**EXPLANATION**

[image]

Comment: yeah, i like this! it's explicit and simple enough especially considering the simple input.  thx for the concise and precise answer summary!  =)

Comment: what about the following (less the \\ it works)...text = text.replaceAll("</?[bip]>", "");

Comment: @JaJ : Yes you can use like that also . In some languages (different regex falour) '/' meaning is different , that is why i sciped that also.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Jsoup` clean with `Whitespace`. `Whitespace` is extensible to include the attributes which are to be left out too.

Per the javadoc here

> Whitelists define what HTML (elements and attributes) to allow through
>   the cleaner. Everything else is removed. ...
>
> If you need to allow more through (please be careful!), tweak a base
>   whitelist with:
>
> - addTags(java.lang.String...)
> - addAttributes(java.lang.String, java.lang.String...)
> - addEnforcedAttribute(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
> - addProtocols(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String...)

In your code:

```
String text = "<b>Remove <i>bold</i> and italics</b>";
        System.out.println(text);
        String doc =  Jsoup.clean(text, new Whitelist());
        System.out.println(doc);
```

Gives:

```
<b>Remove <em>bold</i> and italics</b>
Remove bold and italics
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex to parse HTML, using something like `JSoup` library would make your life easy and make it more extensible. Here is some sample code

```
   Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
   Elements elements = doc.getElementsByTag("b");
   for (Element pre : elements) {
             pre.remove();
    }
```

To remove italics replace `"b"` with `"i"`

**Update**

I have not tested the following code, but it may work.

JSoup allows to select like css selectors, so something like `doc.select("strong, em, b, i");` should return `Elements`

[Link to documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: thx, is there a whitelist of some sort where I can specific "b" and "i" and "em" and "strong" etc, and have just one replace?  how could I replace all of them at once instead have n number of iterations based base on specifying the tag type per getElementsByTag()?